# Terraform: Error while loading schemas for plugin components

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, devops

I have an Azure DevOps Build pipeline that publishes the entire repository as an artifact to be used with the Release pipeline.

```
# Publish artifacts to be used in release
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish artifacts' 
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'TerraformModule'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The build pipeline triggers the creation of a release pipeline where I try to deploy the terraform configuration.

I can successfully run `terraform init` in this pipeline but when I try to run `plan` or `apply`, I get the following error:

[image: log output]

Looking at the screenshot, it looks like it tries to execute the command from `/usr/local/bin` instead of what I specified in the step? Confused by this. Below is the yaml for my `plan` step:

```
steps:
- task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-release-task.TerraformTaskV3@3
  displayName: 'terraform plan'
  inputs:
    provider: aws
    command: plan
    workingDirectory: '/home/vsts/work/r1/a/_terraform/TerraformModule/Projects/Potentium/Prod'
    environmentServiceNameAWS: 'AWS-Terraform-Build'
```

I manually changed `workingDirectory` to where the Artifacts from the build pipeline were downloaded to. See log below for example:

```
2022-08-14T23:41:31.3359557Z Downloaded TerraformModule/Projects/Potentium/Prod/main.tf to /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_terraform/TerraformModule/Projects/Potentium/Prod/main.tf
```

The `plan` step in my build pipeline executes without any issues so I have a feeling it is something to do with the artefacts/extraction that is occurring in the download step. Looking for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with the extraction phase, when using `ExtractFiles@1`   doing a similar thing with terraform. I think there's a bug in it, I could not get it to extract files back to the root of `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` unless the root folder was included in the archiv, I am using `ArchiveFiles@2`. So I was ending up with `/opt/az_devops/_work/*/s/s`

My solution, was to shell out a command to do the extraction. No problems extracting to the root of `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`

Just remember if you're running a subsequent terraform plan, by default the working directory `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` will change between runs. So ensure you use these variables rather than an explicit reference.